# The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory

Tags: php

Anyone know why this:

```
<?PHP
$title = trim($_POST['title']);
$description = trim($_POST['description']);

// Array of allowed image file formats 
$allowedExtensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'jfif', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp');

foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
  if ($file['tmp_name'] > '') {
    if (!in_array(end(explode(".",
            strtolower($file['name']))),
            $allowedExtensions)) {
      echo '<div class="error">Invalid file type.</div>';
    }
  }
}

if (strlen($title) < 3)
  echo '<div class="error">Too short title</div>';
else if (strlen($description) > 70)
  echo '<div class="error">Too long desccription.</div>';

else {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'c:\wamp\www\uploads\images/');
}
```

Gives:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\wamp\www\upload.php on line 41

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php1AB.tmp' to 'c:\wamp\www\uploads\images/' in C:\wamp\www\upload.php on line 41

Comment: Yes. It cannot be a directory

Comment: Actually this warning is explained in the php manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php.

Comment: I was getting this error when the file name was blank - so a bit of misdirection. I did a check to ensure that the file did exist and was named correctly and all was good.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's because you're moving a file and it thinks you're trying to rename that file to the second parameter (in this case a directory).

it should be:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'c:/wamp/www/uploads/images/'.$file['name']);
```

Comment: use forward slashes instead of backslashes

Comment: The example is here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp Even with that, I wasn't paying attention to the fact that the second parameter should have been a file, not a dir. 3 points for googledorf

Answer (score 12):

You are specifying to move a file to a directory; neither PHP's `move_uploaded_file` nor its `copy` is as smart as a shell's copy -- you have to specify a *filename*, not a directory, for the destination.

So, one simple solution would be to take the [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) of the source file and append that to the destination directory.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the second argument to `move_uploaded_file` should be a full file name instead of just the directory name. Also, probably only a style issue, but you should use consistent slashes in `'c:\wamp\www\uploads\images/'`

Answer (score 1):

Because PHP is not a shell. You're trying to copy the file into the `c:\wamp\www\uploads\images` directory, but PHP doesn't know you mean that when you execute (within the `move_uploaded_file` function):

```
copy($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'c:\wamp\www\uploads\images/');
```

This command tells it to rename the file to `c:\wamp\www\uploads\images/`, which it can't do because that's the name of an existing directory.

Instead, do this:

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 
    'c:\wamp\www\uploads\images/' . basename($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want just copy the file in two Dir different, try this :

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target.$pic1))
{
  copy("C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-5.3.9/www/.../images/".$pic1, "C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-5.3.9/www/.../images/thumbs/".$pic1)
}
```

You should write the complete path "C:/..."

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the extension to the name file.

```
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'].".jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

FIRSTLY FIND YOUR CURRENT DIRECTORY echo getcwd();  IF YOU FIND THE CURRENT DIRECTORY SO MOVE THEM ANOTHER DIRECTORY
FOR EXAMPLE = echo getcwd(); these output is "your live directory name" like that -> /opt/lampp/htdocs/product  and create new directory anywhere but your current directory help to go another directory ***

> plz read carefully very thinking answer

---

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It will be like below in phalcon 3.42

```
if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true) {
        // Print the real file names and sizes
        foreach ($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file) {

            //Print file details
            echo $file->getName(), " ", $file->getSize(), "\n";

            //Move the file into the application
            $file->moveTo($this->config->application->uploadsDir.$file->getName());
        }
    }
```