# file not uploading, not moving cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

In my cakePHP project, on a uploading file, am facing below issue:

`pr($resume['tmp_name']);` is returning the file path yet file is not physically present in that location and interestingly `if (move_uploaded_file($resume['tmp_name'], 'resumes/'))` is returning true and yet file is not moved to that location.

Note: `'resumes/'` folder is present in same directory of the controller.

Any suggestions? I got to upload two files from that view

Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618432/1528701 has solved my issue

Comment: If you are on linux or Mac check the chmode of resume folder, and change it to 777

Comment: sadly this works on windows7

Comment: have checked enctype of the form??? you should add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your usercontroller like this

```
public function property() {

 if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
     //die();
     $file = $this->request->data['Document']['submittedfile'];

     //$this->pdfadd1->save($this->request->data);
     move_uploaded_file($this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cakephp3/cakephp1/cakephp/app/webroot/files/' . $this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name']);
```

Comment: changed to `if (move_uploaded_file($resume['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/rm/app/webroot/files/')) {` is throwing move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory