# Character encoding error in name of files uploaded to server

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am uploading files from an Android phone to a server via (java and) PHP. The problem is that special characters like éáő are changed to characters like this (�) in the file's name. The PHP code:

```
$target_path = "./upload/"; 
function check_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    //$data = htmlspecialchars($data);  --> runs to error
    mb_strlen($data, 'UTF-8');
    return $data;
}
$target_path = $target_path . basename(check_input(($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])));
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
```

Comment: Did you try passed `encoding='UTF-8'` parameter to `htmlspecialchars` method?

Comment: Like I showed in the example, htmlspecialchars runs onto error: `move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in` (filename with path)

Comment: Actually you have error in line where is `move_uploaded_file` method. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2618432/1288306).