# Could not edit image from database PDO PHP

Tags: php, html, file, pdo

I can succesfully save the image from my database using this code

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-update'])){


    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE id=:id";
    $query= $db_con->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $id));

    while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $images_ = $row['image'];
        $files_ = $row['file'];
    }

$file_image = $_FILES['image-files'];
$file_image_Name = $_FILES['image-files']['name'];
$file_image_TmpName = $_FILES['image-files']['tmp_name'];
$file_image_Size = $_FILES['image-files']['size'];
$file_image_Error = $_FILES['image-files']['error'];
$file_image_Type = $_FILES['image-files']['type'];

if(!empty($_FILES['image-files']['tmp_name'])){
//handle first upload
    $file_image_Ext = explode('.', $file_image_Name);
    $file_image_ActualExt = strtolower(end($file_image_Ext));
    $file_image_allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

    if(in_array($file_image_ActualExt, $file_image_allowed)){
        if($file_image_Error === 0){
            if($file_image_Size < 1000000){
                $file_image_NameNew = "image-".uniqid('',true).'.'.$file_image_ActualExt;
                $file_image_Destination = 'uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles_images/' .$file_image_NameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($file_image_TmpName, $file_image_Destination);
            }else{
                echo "You file size is too big!";
            }
        }else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file!";  
        }
    }else{
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }

}else{
    $file_image_NameNew = '';
}

if($user->InsertArticle($articleTitle,$date_today,$bodyContent,$file_image_NameNew))
{
    header("Location:admin-index?UploadedSuccesfully!");
}
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is edit the image but it seems like my code is missing something and I couldn't figure out why is it not succesfully editing.

Here's my code for editing the image from database

```
$location = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$fileTmpNameLocation = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
        //allow file types
        $fileExtLocation = explode('.', $location);
        $fileActualExtLocation = strtolower(end($fileExtLocation));
        $allowedLocation = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

        if(in_array($fileActualExtLocation, $allowedLocation)){
            $fileNameNewLocation = $images_;
            $fileDestinationLocation = 'uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles_images/' .$fileNameNewLocation;

            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpNameLocation, $fileDestinationLocation);
        }
    }else{
        $fileNameNewLocation = '';
    }

if($user->UpdateFile($id,$title,$content,$fileNameNewLocation)){

        $user->Redirect('edit-index.php?UpdatedSuccesfully');
    }else{
        echo "There's something wrong!";
    }
```

Here's my `UpdateFile Method`

```
public function UpdateFile($id,$title, $content, $image){
        try{
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE article SET title=:title, content=:content, image=:image WHERE id=:id");

            $stmt->bindParam(":title", $title);
            $stmt->bindParam(":content", $content);
            $stmt->bindParam(":image", $image);
            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);

            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;

        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Could someone help me out please.

EDIT:

```html
<form action = "edit.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">

  <label for="title">Title of the Article</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
   <br \>
   <label for="bodyContent">Content</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="content" name="content"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
   <br>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Upload Image Only</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" id="image">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php
         if(empty($images_)){
          //nnothing to display
         }else{
          echo "<img src='uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles_images/$images_' class='img-responsive img-rounded'>";  
         }
        ?>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Upload File</label>
        <input type="file" name="files" class="form-control-file" id="files">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <?php
          if(empty($files_)){
           //nothing to display
          }else{
           echo "<a href='uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles/$files_' download>".$files_."</p>";
          }
         ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>> 
    </div> 
   </div>
  <br>
  
  <button type="submit" name="btn-update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> 
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: without the HTML for this, it's impossible to tell whether or not you're using the same files array name.

Comment: Oh sorry about that . I'

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I already edited sir my question

Comment: Use the following error handling links to see what happens: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: There's no error sir

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner There is an error sir . `The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory`

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618418/the-second-argument-to-copy-function-cannot-be-a-directory in Googling the error. That is one of other results to consult. Also make sure that the file/folder are writeable.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner We are actually the same